# Set relations on reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

This is a question regarding  reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity.

Let $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (c, b)\}$

From the above, I understand that A is a reflexive due to $\{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c)\}$

For symmetry, the definition states that $x,y \in R, x = y$ implies $y = x$. Hence, $(y,x) \in \ R$. Based on this, I will assume A is not symmetry as if it is to be symmetry, it needs to have $(c, b), (b, c)$ in the sets making it $R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (c, b), (b,c)\}$. Am I right on this point?

As for transitivity, I am not sure if it applies here but from the definition, it basically means to have transitivity, I will need to have something like $(a, b), (b, c), (a, c)$. In this case, I do not see any hence it is not a transitivity.

My answer to this is that *A is relexive only*.

Is it also right for me to think that if the I do not see the elements in the sets that can form one of the above relations, then A will not have that relation?

Answer (score 3):

Your justifications are wrong. The three relation properties are are all universally quantified predicates over elements of $A$. To show that a property does *not* hold, then, it suffices to find elements that satisfy the premises of the predicate but fail the conclusion.

To show that $R$ is not symmetric here, note that $(c,b)\in R$ but $(b,c)\not\in R$. However, $R$ is indeed transitive, and I leave it to you to show it by examining all possible cases.

Comment: Thanks Parcly. Please correct me if I am wrong. For transitive in this example, it is transitive because we have (c,c) and (b,b) and this implies (c,b) because its belongs to R?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz No. The only two possible ways to have $xRy$ and $yRz$ here, other than the trivial ones, are $cRb,bRb$ and $cRc,bRb$. For these it is easy to check that $xRz$ as well.

Comment: Hope I am getting it, please bear with me. Instead of cRb, we change it to aRb. Then there must be a relation that is aRa and bRb for it to be transitive?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz No. The formal definition of transitivity is $\forall a,b,c\in A:aRb\land bRc\implies aRc$. Check for each of the $27$ possibilities - shouldn't take too long.

Comment: @SunnyBoiz Alternatively, look for counter examples: relation $\def\R{\mathop{\cal R}}\R$ is *not* transitive when $\exists a~\exists b~\exists c:(a\R b\wedge b\R c\wedge\lnot a\R c)$ .